# XPathExpression cannot sum digit

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I parse `XML` and using `XPath` want to evaluate summ.

I try:

```
long resultSum = 0L;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(getOutputFileName());
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
String xPathExpression = "sum(//entries//entry/@field)";
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(xPathExpression);
resultSum = (Long) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```

But, I'have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

In this line:

```
resultSum = (Long) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XPathConstants.NUMBER` evaluates to a `Double`, in order to assign its result to a `Long` you'll need to do something like this:

```
resultSum = ((Double) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER)).longValue();
```